# Не работает get в библеотеке Jsoup

Tags: android, kotlin, jsoup

Не работает в котлине метод.

```
val doc :Document! = Jsoup.connect("https://stackoverflow.com").get()
```

Причем в аналогичном методе на java все работает.
Ошибку выдает на .get()

[image: Ошибки]

Comment: приложите лог ошибки текстом и строку 40 из MainActivity.kt иначе помочь так никто не сможет :(

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый нажав на галочку слева.

Answer (score 0):

Ваша ошибка звучит так:

```
android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
```

Вам нужно делать запрос при помощи [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) например. Этот вариант подходит если нужно сделать обновление View только после того как завершится загрузка с вашего ресурса. Вот например:

```
private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

  @Override
  protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
    String title ="";
    Document doc;
    try {
      doc = Jsoup.connect("http://google.com/").get();
      title = doc.title();
      System.out.print(title);
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return title;   
  } 


  @Override
  protected void onPostExecute(String result) {        
    //if you had a ui element, you could display the title
    ((TextView)findViewById (R.id.myTextView)).setText (result);
  }
}
```

Дальше чтобы сделать вызов этого AsyncTask после строки `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` сделайте вызов:

```
new MyTask().execute();
```

Вот [вопрос-первоисточник](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14247339/parsing-with-jsoup-throws-error-networkonmainthreadexception), так же здесь вы сможете найти дополнительную информацию касательно вашей проблемы.